# What is the difference between 乗り越すand 乗り過ごす?

Tags: word-choice

I don't understand the difference between these two words. In my textbook they appear like "miss the stop" (norisugosu) and "pass my station" (norikosu), but they both sound like you don't go out the train when you should.

Comment: What else do you know about these verbs? Do you know how they are written in Japanese? (By the way, a Japanese speaker could ask exactly the same question, saying that in their textbook "miss the stop" and "pass my station" both sound like one didn't get off the train when one should have, even though their difference wasn't explained in the textbook.)

Comment: Norikosu - 乗り越す, Norisugosu - 乗り過ごす.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I know it could also sound weird for a native Japanese speaker in English. I'm just asking what's the difference between them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**乗り過ごす** (nori-sugosu): "to miss one's stop (by mistake)". This happens typically when a passenger was sleeping. After you do this, you usually get on another train going in the opposite direction.

**乗り越す** (nori-kosu): This can refer to the same thing as 乗り過ごす, but usually refers to something different, "to go beyond one's stop designated by your ticket (intentionally)". This typically happens when you change your destination after getting on a train/bus. After you do this, you usually get off the train near your new destination, and pay for the additional distance at a fare adjustment machine/office (aka [乗り越し精算](https://www.japanallover.com/2009/11/fare-adjustment-machines/)).