# Meaning of 過ぎ in 20日過ぎに海行くんだ

Tags: words

> 20日過ぎに海行くんだ

I'm pretty sure this means

> going to the sea in 20 days

but 過ぎる signifies elapsed time, so could it possibly be

> going to the beach **for** 20 days

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course @Chocolate has already given the [correct answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/63103/1628), but let me just note that the meaning of 過ぎる of "elapsing time" that you mentioned is correct, although I would rather think of it as *passing* a particular point in time (or *exceeding* a particular fixed period of time).

> 8時過ぎに電話してください = 8時が過ぎたら電話してください
>   Please call me after 8 o'clock = Please call me when 8 o'clock has passed

Here it refers passing a particular point in time (8 o'clock); similarly the transitive 過ごす can also be used for passing a physical location, as for example in 乗り過ごす (see ["Norikosu" vs. "Norisugosu"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60888/1628)).

Answer (score 13):

「～～過ぎ」 can mean "past~~" "after~~".

Examples from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E/#je-38846):

> 20日過ぎに (sometime) after the twentieth
>   8時過ぎに電話してね Call me after eight.

Comment: I will translate it as `over` just like `20 days is over since ... (some action)`.

Comment: ^ That would be 「(some action)から20日が過ぎた」